# Book about a young man who goes questing with a magic knife made from his gardening tool

Tags: story-identification, books, magical-items

I read this book back in middle school (about 1998-2000), and remember very little about the plot. What I do remember is this:

1. The main character is a young man who leaves his farm on a quest for a magical something or other. His only weapon is a knife that he had forged from his gardening trowel.
2. Said gardening trowel was already a knife (or short sword) beforehand. It has a large magical stone either on the pommel or the hilt.
3. Near the end of the book, the stone ends up saving the young man's life because he had been bitten/scratched/bled on by a creature (I remember "Wyrm" being mentioned) that's very essence was poison. The stone healed him of the affliction the wyrm caused.
4. He kills the dreaded wyrm, collects the magical macguffin and then returns home to the farm where he reforges the knife back into a trowel.

I believe it might have been the first (or second) of a series, but my library didn't have any of the other parts of the series (this was back before I learned about inter-library loan).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

That story was called "[Hero's Song](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/294937.Hero_s_Song)" by Edith Pattou;

The blurb is as follows;

> Hero's Song takes the reader on an epic journey through dark-aged
>   Eirren, a parallel to Ireland. Collun is a young man and simple
>   **gardener** living at peace with his family in their small humble home,
>   but when his beloved sister disappears, Collun must go in search of
>   her. Along the road he finds himself in the company of an aspiring
>   bard,Talisen, a wizard, Crann who dies, a prince of magical beings,
>   Silian an Ellyl which is kind of an elf, and a fiery archer with a
>   mission of her own,Brie whose father was ordered to be killed by
>   Collun's father and dresses up like a boy. The journey is perilous and
>   filled with dangerous encounters. Collun learns the worst is yet to
>   come when he finds the only way to reach his sister is by killing a
>   horrific beast,that is called a **Firewurme**, which few have seen and
>   lived to tell the tale,because it secrets a fluid that eats your
>   flesh. And Collun travels to his father's home, who he didn't know,
>   with Brie and builds a garden there.

[image: Hero's song cover]

Comment: How is this story matching the description in the question? You need to provide some details

Comment: I've updated the info. It certainly seems very close to the description.

Comment: The blurb came from a deleted Wikipedia article, http://speedydeletion.wikia.com/wiki/Songs_of_Eirren

Answer (score 3):

Blast!   The initial description matched closely to Andre Nortons "[Steel Magic](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/175891.Steel_Magic)"  where three children each have an item of dinnerware grow to become a magical tool they need to complete a quest. The other details don't match though.

[image: Steel Magic cover]

> *A final stand for Avalon... Sara, Greg, and Eric Lowry are exploring
>   the woods near their uncle's Hudson Valley estate when they are
>   magically transported to the land of Avalon. There they meet Huon,
>   Warden of the West. When he tells them that the forces of darkness
>   have stolen the three talismans that protect Avalon-King Arthur's
>   sword, Excalibur; Merlin's ring; and Huon's horn-the children set off
>   on a quest to find the three tokens of power. For Avalon stands as a
>   wall between the Dark and the mortal world. And if Avalon falls, so
>   does Earth....*